# Impedance matching resistor in series or parallel between signal stages?

Tags: operational-amplifier, impedance

I would like to amplify a signal from a charge-sensitive preamplifier and record the signal with a spectrum analyzer. The preamp has 50 Ohm output impedance and the analyzer has 50 Ohm input impedance. To amplify this signal I am using a current feedback opamp. I have some confusion as to whether the 50 Ohm resistors should be in series or parallel in this circuit. In which cases is either series or parallel used?

[image]

Comment: Depends if the thing you're matching initially has a high impedance or low impedance.

Comment: @ThePhoton I'm trying to add this gain stage between two other 50 Ohm impedance stages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the input of the amp you have a realtively high impedance, putting the 50\$\Omega\$ in series would just make it that much higher, so instead it should be in parallel on the input.

On the output you have the opposite, a low impedance from the amplifier, so you need the 50\$\Omega\$ to be in series.

In the schematic all you should need to do is change R2 to be in series with the output, the input side should be okay.

If you want it to be a really good match you would need to take the input and output impedances of the amplifier circuit into consideration and adjust the 50\$\Omega\$ resistors a bit. Basically find the impedances and if you need more to get to 50\$\Omega\$ put resistance in series, if you need less put resistance in parallel. You may find that the output of the opamp isn't lower than 50\$\Omega\$, in that case you would need to add resistance in parallel to bring it down.